# Authenticating another user when using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a .NET MVC 4 application that uses Windows authentication. Some users are administrators, and need to be able to enter data on behalf of other users.

I have a text box where the admin enters the name of another user. How can I check to verify that the text entered is an existing Windows username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`FindByIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) method:

```
string username = "Some username you retrieved from the TextBox";

using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOUR_DOMAIN"))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username))
{
    bool userExists = user != null;
    // here you know whether the user exists or not
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting an answer explaining why you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what's behind all the hate for this question and these answers, but this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can query the Active Directory of your organization for this.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DomainName");
DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
String Name="Richmond";
dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(l=" + Name + "))";
```

See this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6778/How-to-get-User-Data-from-the-Active-Directory

Comment: Actually there's a newer API than DirectoryEntry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx